# Django ORM inner join between tables having foriegn key of third table

Tags: mysql, django

I want to perform an inner join between tables that holds the foreign key of another table in VIEW.PY

[image]

[image]

[image]

The raw query that I am trying to make in django is

```
SELECT * 
FROM table3 t3
inner join table2 t2 on t2.C=t3.E
where t2.B=0 and t2.D=t3.F and 
( (t3.G =1234 and t3.H=0) or (t3.H!=0 and t3.G is null) )
```

how to do this in django Views

Comment: Please share the relevant models.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a few assumptions on your models since you didn't provide them, but this should accomplish what you want.

```
from django.db import models
Table3.objects.select_related('table2').filter(
    F=models.F('table2__D'),
    table2__B=0,
).filter(
    models.Q(G=1234, H=0)
    | models.Q(~models.Q(H=0), G__isnull=True)
)
```